# Align three images next to each other, with another on top of the center image

Tags: html, css

I have four images and I'm trying to put three in the center and one on top of the center image like this:

```
               [image2]
[image1]       [image3]        [image4]
```

Here's an image example of what I mean: http://prnt.sc/a9iyu6

The only issue is that all the images are underneath each other.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<img src="images1.png" /> 
<img src="images2.png" />
<img src="images3.png" />
<img src="images4.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7xj2usc/)

This is the css:

```
#container{
  display:flex
}
#centered{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

And the updated HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250/CCCCCC" /> 
<div id="centered">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/FEFEFE" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/AAAAAA" />
</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250/BBBBBB" />
</div>
```

[Flex-box is pretty cool](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Just play around with this for a bit and you'll get it just the way you want it.

Comment: Brilliant, I've never heard of Flex-box before!

Answer (score 0):

What do You think about solutions like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/09qb6w6p/4/)

I wrote simply CSS which should do the job for You:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;  
}

img {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}

img:nth-child(1){
  margin-top: 100px;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

img:nth-child(4){
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 33%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/?v=2"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
```

In that solution You don't have to add anything to your code except some CSS. Of course You can try to adjust margins to what You axactly want to get.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like `image1` and `image4` to surround `image2` and `image3` like this: http://prntscr.com/a9iyu6, rather than (what it is currently) this: http://prntscr.com/a9izo1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
div {
  padding-top:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

img {
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top:-100px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="images1.png" /> 
<img src="images2.png" />
<img src="images3.png" />
<img src="images4.png" />
</div>
```